# Remove or change selection color on List items that have NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui-list

I have a List of items like this:

```
List(viewModel.requests) { request in
    AbsenceView(approvalRequest: request)
        .background(
            NavigationLink(
                "",
                destination: ApprovalRequestDetailsViewController.SwiftUI(approvalRequest: request)
            ).opacity(0)
        )
    }
```

The reason NavigationLink is inside the background modifier is because I don't want my List items to change in any way. If I wrapped the View inside NavigationLink, the List row height expanded and there was an arrow to the right that I didn't want.

But now, every time I press an item in my List, there's a grey selection colour, like this:

[image]

What can I do to get rid of this selection color entirely? I went through every solution I find online and nothing works.